# Level lowering the generalized Fermat equation

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, discriminant

For the Fermat equation

$x^p$ + $y^p$ = $z^p$

the discriminant of the Frey curve is

$\Delta$ = $16(xyz)^{2p}$

which satisfies Ribet's level lowering requirements for the conductor. This is key to proving FLT.

For the generalized Fermat equation

$x^p$ + $y^q$ = $z^r$

I suppose the discriminant is

$\Delta$ = $16x^{2p}y^{2q}z^{2r}$

Let $n=pqr$.

Then integers can be found that satisfy $ord_l(\Delta)\equiv 0 \pmod n$

In particular, all integers $(a,b,c)$ such that they are pairwise relatively prime and

$x=a^{qr}$,
$y=b^{pr}$,
$z=c^{pq}$

appear to satisfy $ord_l(\Delta)\equiv 0 \pmod n$.  This is an infinite class
of triples for the generalized Fermat equation that do not have non-trivial solutions because of FLT.  Whenever you can factor the FLT exponent $n$ into three factors, each of those can be used as an exponent in a generalized Fermat equation.

The important question is a more general case.  Even though we just ruled out an infinite class of solutions, it only covers $n=pqr$. What about any $(p,q,r)$ where $p,q,r\ge3$?

**Edit 2:**

I want to rephrase the question for clarity.

For the generalized Fermat equation

$x^p$ + $y^q$ = $z^r$

The discriminant of the Frey curve is

$\Delta$ = $16x^{2p}y^{2q}z^{2r}$

Silverman's version of Ribet's requirement is

$ord_l(\Delta)\equiv 0 \pmod n$

For the discriminant of the Frey curve for the generalized Fermat equation we can write

$\Delta=\alpha \Delta'$ where

$\Delta'=(abc)^{2 \min(p,q,r)}$

Obviously,

$ord_l(\Delta')\equiv 0 \pmod n$ and

$ord_l(\alpha)\equiv 0 \pmod n$ if $l$ is not a factor of $\alpha$, but

what do we do if $l$ is a factor of $\alpha$? Is there any way to reset and go again on $\alpha$ (so to speak)?

References would be Silverman pp.253-255 of Rational Points on Elliptic Curves, and Ribet's original article "On modular representations of Gal(Q bar/Q) arising from modular forms" Invent. math. 100, 431-476 (1990).

Comment: $a^p+b^q= c^r$ an integer solution.
The elliptic curve $E : y^2 =x(x-a^p)(x+b^q)= \prod_{i=1}^3 (x-\alpha_i)$ has discriminant $\Delta = 16\prod_{i,j} (\alpha_i-\alpha_j)=16a^{2p} b^{2q} c^{2r}$. You **assume** for some $m$ we have a modular form $f \in S_2(\Gamma_0(m\Delta ))$ such that $L(s,E)=L(s,f)$ (what is [$m$ ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor_of_an_elliptic_curve)). Then you ask if we can find a modular form $g \in S_2(\Gamma_0(N)),N |m\Delta$ with the same Galois representation as $f$ (if $N$ is small enough we'll use $\dim S_2(\Gamma_0(N)) =0$ so $(a,b,c)$ didn't exist)

Comment: http://math.bu.edu/people/ghs/papers/FermatOverview.pdf makes things quite precise.